# How can I set a custom syntax highlight color for python docstrings in atom?

Tags: python, atom-editor

How can I set a custom syntax highlight color for python docstrings in atom?
I would like to be able to use different colors for triple-quoted '''docstrings''' and single-quoted 'string'.

Follow-up, after trying suggestions from @FedericoBau:

I've deleted all but the built-in themes, and edited the stylesheet as per Federico's instructions. Results are shown in the screenshot below. Base theme is OneDark, unmodified except by changing ~/.atom/styles.less as shown in the screenshot. The docstrings are still shown the same as ordinary strings.

[image]

Comment: @katherineLong  That's awesome. I added to my answer your reference so if someone in future need it can have the full picture. One thing if my answer helped you I suggest you to mark is as accepted so that your question can be removed from the not answered queue. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is what should look like the JSON for Python Docs String:

```
atom-text-editor::shadow .string.quoted.double.block.python {
  color: #282a2e;

  // Quotes
  .punctuation.definition {
    // color: #282a2e;
  }
}
```

---

### Important note

**As suggested by Katharine Long, you should use Brunel-syntax, have a look at her answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65587320/13903942).**

---

You may create you own theme or update an existing one.

Press `Ctrl+Shift+P`   or `⌘ + ⌥ + P` （macOS and start typing "Generate Syntax Theme" to generate a new theme package. Select "Generate Syntax Theme," and you'll be asked for the path where your theme will be created. Let's call ours motif-syntax.

Open a file written in the language that you want to specify the colors for in Atom.

If you want to do the same thing from the menu, go `choosePackages > Command Palette > Toggle`, and type log cursor scope into the Command Palette, which has just appeared, and select Editor: Log Cursor Scope.

If the above did not work try this other way. Go from the menu top left corner file, then click on style-sheet.

It will open a new style-sheet called `base.less.` Add the JSON below and save.

---

### Documentation & Referance##

- [Creating a Syntax Theme](https://flight-manual.atom.io/hacking-atom/sections/creating-a-theme/#creating-a-syntax-theme)
- [How can we customize the syntax highlighting of Atom Editor](https://qiita.com/kouichi-c-nakamura/items/0c0080308e651d8704ad)
- [flight-manual.atom.io](https://flight-manual.atom.io/)

Comment: When I select Editor: Log Cursor Scope while on a docstring, I get a box indicating source.python and string.quoted, same as with an ordinary string.

Comment: ok, that's what you get automatically right? Did you add into the JSON the code from my answer?

Comment: Yes, I put it in styles/base.less. After doing that and selecting the new theme, it changes the theme as expected, but docstrings still look exactly like ordinary strings.

Comment: Is base.less the correct place to make the change?

Comment: I also put it in styles.less

Comment: @KatharineLong are you sure there isn't other theme already and conflict with your custom one?

Answer (score 0):

After more experimentation, it seems this is done successfully in the Brunel-syntax theme when using MagicPython.

Most themes don't seem to recognize any syntactical distinction between strings, docstrings, etc, in which case nothing done to styles.less will color docstrings and ordinary strings differently.

To see how it's done, see the code in
~/.atom/packages/brunel-syntax/styles/syntax/python/magicpython/python.less.

This does what I was looking for, and I can adapt it for use in my own style. Here's how it looks:

[image]